# How do I permanently disable the "Similar Contacts Found" pop up?

Tags: contacts

Whatever name I enter into the first name field I get a pop up of dozens of "similar contacts found" that takes up half the screen, so I have to hit x to close it so I can continue entering into the fields. Can I disable this feature?

Comment: It could be the problem is the default DeDupe/Match rule at civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1. You may need to make a new Supervised rule, as it sounds like your current one is finding too many matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn it off totally if you need although you probably want to tweak the rules as Pete has highlighted. If you did want to turn it off you can get to display settings and turn off the display (by setting to never) of possible matching contacts.

[image: Menu Location]

[image: Popup Display Setting]